# How can I perform spatial query using openlayers and geoserver?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I have on my geoserver 2 shp files : pipes and buildings.
I would like to put a form on my openlayers page that when user click it , he can choose distance (10m , 20m, etc...) and get a result of => all pipes in distance X from buildings.

How can I do that using geoserver (I don't wish to upload my shp files to any database because they are being updated regularly)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend you to read something about CQL. Good starting point might be [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html) and [there](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/cat). You should be probably the most interested in DWITHIN geometric predicate.

PS: And [there](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html).

Comment: Thank you , I will read it. Is there any online example for GUI that will go with it - for doing dynamic queries..

Comment: Not that I know of. But you should be OK with simple HTML form having change events binding.